# How Firebase push notification work on IOS?

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, pushy

I want to create my own push notification mechanism for my own iOS applications.

I compared some services like [pushy.me](http://pushy.me) or Google Firebase. I think Pushy is the only service that can push notifications independent from Apple APNs, but it uses simple HTTP long-poll requests to receive notifications (in the iOS SDK).

But how does Firebase work? Does it still depend on Apple's APNs? How will it affect my battery life?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

Comment: Thank you, but what do fcm sdk on ios? Developers can use default notification interfaces of ios!

Comment: Correction -- Pushy (pushy.me) uses APNs to deliver notifications, definitely not long-poll HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) delivers push notification to iOS devices via Apple's Push Notifications service. Also FCM extends functionality of push notifications.
How FCM extends?

- FCM works with iOS and Android. Cool feature if you have the app for both platforms;
- Don't need to develop backend for sending notifications, storing pn tokens etc. Just register your app in the Google Developer Console and follow User Guides. For sending a push just execute request to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` with params;
- Broadcast notifications. The app subscribes to a `topic` and then you can send a notification to all `topic` subscribers. Very cool;
- Upstream messages (send data to the server)

Also Google has others services you can extend FCM with. For example Cloud Functions.

I didn't find that FCM integration take big affect to battery life in my apps.

UPDATE:
FCM framework sends push notification token (and other info) to Google services. Also as I mentioned above you can subscribe app for a specific `topic`. Than Google knows which device needs to send a push to. 
There is a possibility to setup FCM in iOS automatically(with using method swizzling). FCM exchange `AppDelegate` methods and knows your's device pn token.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) utilizes APNs (Apple push notifications services) for delivering the messages to iOS devices. 
So basically, FCM wraps iOS methods like `registerForRemoteNotifications` or `didReceiveRemoteNotification` using method swizzling (BTW, you can disable this if you wish, although I can't see any reason...).

On the technical side - the phone is keeping an open connection with APNs and this tunnel is used for sending the messages themselves.